# Getting started with Angular2: Custom tags are not recognized and not processed

Tags: html, angular, cloud9

I'm trying to setup angular2, but my custom html tags are not processed.

I wonder how to get things running... quite a bit confusing.

I provide some **code**, so you guys can see!

**app/main.ts**

```
import { bootstrap } from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

**app/app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'timo',
  template: '<h1>Sample Text</h1>'
})

export class AppComponent { }
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Sample Site</title>

        <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

        <script>

            System.config({
                packages: { app: { defaultExtension: 'js' }}
            });

            System.import('./app/main');

        </script>


    </head>
    <body>

        <timo>loading ...</timo>

    </body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "workspace",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.17",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.31",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^1.8.10"
  }
}
```

All that shows up is just "... loading".

Comment: It would be helpful if you post your code.

Comment: too much code. too much files. too much folders.

Comment: I did the things in this tutorial: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html, and I also did three more tuts and the problem repeats over those different configurations ...

Comment: Do you see any errors in your browser console?

Comment: a 404 error on /angular-2-template/app/js/main.js

Comment: you must be missing main.ts file from above article.

Comment: hey @Sanket !!, I have a main.ts file. It simply doesn't compile to JS...

Comment: solution!!!! :D i am happy. :D everything works. I has to type "NPM RUN TSC" !!!!

Comment: when you run npm start command, it also starts TypeScript compiler in watch mode. This takes care of TS to JS conversion. These details you can refer in your package.json under scripts tag.

Comment: @Sanket !!! I have this problem again. I have provided some code. please have a look!

Comment: Take index.html, package.json and systemjs.config.js from quickstart article.

Comment: And y r u still using beta17, rc4 is out and its preferred you learn that then 4 months old version. Lots have changed